# focusout textfield check if it is number or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focusout

jquery and javascript. I would really appreciate any advice. I wanted to implement like a textfield onfocusout after something input in text field if it is only a number it will add automatically .00 in the end how ever if they input like 2.00  it will not add .00 any more.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$('#tx').on('focusout',  function() {  
     var x=document.getElementById(tx).value;
    if (isNaN(x)) // this is the code I need to change
    {
        $(this).val(`${$(this).val()}`);

    }else{

   $(this).val(`${$(this).val()}.00`);

});

        </script>




</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *tx* is set

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tx').on('focusout',  function() {  
    var x=document.getElementById(tx).value;
    $(this).val(parseInt(x.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,'')||0).toFixed(2));

});    
</script>
```